# React first gives null values and after a while values are initialized

Tags: reactjs, session, redux, roles, react-props

I am trying to create a component to make the validation if the user is authenticated or not.
It is not I am redirecting to log in, however, when I am checking if is it authenticated, first the session is null and after 2000ms says that is authenticated.

**App.js**

```
    function App() {
    
     const session = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:4500/api/user/current`, {
          headers: {
            token: token,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch(login(res.data));
        });
    } else {
      dispatch(logout());
      console.log("no token");
    }
  }, []);
    
      
      console.log(session?.role + " XX S"); //first goes null and then after it is initialized
    
      return (
    
     <Route
                element={
                  <RequireAuth allowedRoles={[3]} session_role={session?.role} /> //session?.role first is null and it is a problem with the logic of validation
                }
              >
                <Route path="/protected" element={<Protected />} />
              </Route>
    
    )
```

***RequireAuth.js***

```
    const RequireAuth = ({ allowedRoles, session_role }) => {
  const session = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
  const location = useLocation();

  console.log(session_role + " ROLE ");

  return session_role?.find((role) => allowedRoles?.includes(role)) ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : session ? (
    <Navigate to="/unauthorised" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  );
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

***Reducer***

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Did you define your initial state in your actions or reducer , where it would be called first?

Comment: As the initial state is null, there is useEffect function in the App.js that makes a GET request to the URL with the token as a header to get the session, and then with the action, the store is defined. I am updating the question

Comment: ok, try dispatching your initial state, before your component loads of app js, use dispatcher from react-redux, or use hook, useEffect(() => useDispatch(initialStateAction)). Let me know if you need pseudocode for this.

Comment: Or if you want to avoid that , or do not want to change that, use loader or any fallback, until you have a session value.

Comment: @SiddharthPachori Can you please provide a solution so I can vote for your contribution
Thanks

Comment: Sure, let me format it.

Comment: @SiddharthPachori Thank you so much since I am initializing and I am calling a useEffect at the App.js to dispatch(login(res.data)); but still the same

Comment: have added the snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let token = 1;
  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeToken() {
      if (token) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(login({
            user: {
              id: 'id',
              name: 'name',
              surname: 'surname',
              email: 'email',
              role: 'role',
            },
          }))
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        dispatch(logout());
        console.log("no token");
      }
    }
    initializeToken();
  }, [dispatch]);

  const session = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const sessionObject = session ? JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(session)) : null ;
  console.log(sessionObject, 'sessionObject');

  const isAuth = sessionObject ? sessionObject.isLoggedIn : null ;
  console.log(isAuth + "isAuth");
  const role = sessionObject ? sessionObject.user && session.user.user ? session.user.user.role : null : null
  console.log(role, 'role')


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="unauthorised" element={<Unauthorised />} />
          <Route
            element={
              <RequireAuth allowedRoles={[3]} session_role={session?.role} />
            }
          >
            <Route path="/protected" element={<Protected />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Have used setTimeout instead of api , it can simulate same stuff. The reason behind null is parsing the data, not the initial state i thought it would be. The above code should do the trick.

Comment: What would be an initial state, because they already are null

Comment: initialState as in, until your api responds with a true value, or however quick that would be, it should have mounted value and when it responds you dispatch your actions and session.role would have a value

Comment: there would always be a delay on your api response as its a promise, promises are asynchronous in nature, so have a fallback value or set initial state until your api responds.

Comment: have updated the snippet